# Deleting duplicate rows with condition

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have posted a similar question before, but this one is a little modified.

I have a table with 4 columns as shown below.

> ```
> ITEMCHARGE     CPT4       EFF_DATE    CPT4MOD
> 326.8         29075       20101204    GO
> 326.8         29075       20110104    GO
> 326.8         29075       20110204    GO
> 326.8         29075       20110406    GO
> 352.69        29075       20090611    GO
> 352.69        29075       20090917    GO
> 352.69        29075       20100614    GO
> 352.69        29075       20100722    GO
> ```

Now, if `CPT4` and `CPT4MOD` match, I need to keep the rows with distinct `ITEMCHARGE` (with latest `EFF_DATE`). The output should be like below:

```
    ITEMCHARGE  CPT4    EFF_DATE    CPT4MOD
       326.8    29075   20110406    GO
       352.69   29075   20100722    GO
```

There are 2 distinct `ITEMCHARGE` for the same `CPT4` and `CPT4MOD`. So we took the latest `EFF_DATE` row for both of them. It would be very helpful If I can get a linq (with lamda) and SQL version for this.

Comment: it's 4 columns, not 4 rows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would that work? SQL version only.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CPT4, CPT4MOD, ITEMCHARGE ORDER BY EFF_DATE DESC) AS RowNo
    , *
FROM #table
) AS T
WHERE T.RowNo = 1
```

You can check it here:
http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/260027/delting-duplicate-rows-with-condition

Comment: How do I convet this to LINQ?

Comment: I'm just a SQL Developer. :(

Would this tool help?

[link](http://www.sqltolinq.com)